# Parsing a dash-delimited value in a SQL table and doing lookups

Tags: sql, mysql

How do I parse a dash-delimited value in a SQL table and use the different parsed-out values to do lookups in other tables?

Say I have users.nationality, which is a varchar like "41-33-11".  I have the country, city and state tables keyed to those ids, 41 ("Buffalo"), 33 ("NY") and 11 ("USA").

SELECT users.name, users.email, users.nationality FROM users

nationality = "41-33-11"

How do I craft a SELECT statement so to get "Buffalo, NY, USA"?

Comment: Can you redesign your DB schema or this is something you need to work with? I'm asking because it looks like a very poor design.

Comment: multi-valued fields are a sign of poor design.

Comment: @DaveE: Tell us how you *really* feel =)

Comment: Agreed guys.  Wasn't my DB schema.  Sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an inline view to pull out the values so you can then join onto them:

```
JOIN (SELECT SUBSTR(t.nationality, 0, 2) AS city_id,
             SUBSTR(t.nationality, INSTR(t.nationality, '-')+1, 2) AS state_id,
             RIGHT(t.nationality, 2) AS country_id
        FROM USERS t) u
JOIN COUNTRY cntry ON cntry.country_id = u.country_id
JOIN CITY cty ON cty.city_id = u.cty_id
JOIN STATE st ON st.state_id = u.state_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077686/is-there-something-analogous-to-a-split-method-in-mysql), particularly look at using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of string splitting solutions among the [mysql dev comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) by which you can use the split string in a WHERE IN statement.

Answer (score 0):

depends on the SQL you are using. I would generally say it was easier to do in the language you are querying from, for example using PHP's split(). If it's MySQL, then this article should help:
http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

MS SQL has builting split functions I think.