# Apply search criteria on dynamic field table without using grouping or pivoting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following two tables, one table is of person and another table is for storing various dynamic properties/information about the person.

```
 Id | Persons               PersonId | Field  | Value         
----+-------------         ----------+--------+-----------
 1  | Peter                      1   | City   | New York 
 2  | Jane                       1   | Age    | 26
                                 2   | City   | New York
                                 2   | Age    | 50
```

1. Can I apply a search condition in an sql query like person with `age > 25 and city = 'New York'` without `grouping` or `pivoting` the table.
2. What is best way to apply the search criteria with least performance overhead.

Comment: How are you going to pass the parameters, especially the operator (e.g. greater than, equals)?

Comment: I am talking about sql query here.

Comment: But you don't know what the criteria might be, right? Because otherwise something simple like `select PersonId from table2 where [field] = 'age' and [value] > 25` would work.

Comment: but what about combining two conditions? like age and city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT key1.PersonId 
FROM KeyValue key1
    INNER JOIN KeyValue key2 ON key1.PersonId = key2.PersonId
WHERE key1.[Field] = 'Age' and key1.[Value] > 25
    AND key2.[Field] = 'City' and key2.[Value] = 'New York'
```

**Update**

I did some tests and INNER JOIN looks fast enough. Here result and test script

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET STATISTICS IO ON

CREATE TABLE KeyValue (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY CONSTRAINT [PK_KeyValue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,PersonId INT NOT NULL
    ,Field varchar(30) NOT NULL
    ,Value varchar(255) NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT UQ__KeyValue__PersonId_Field UNIQUE (PersonId, Field)
)
GO
--INSERT INTO KeyValue 500K "users", 4 "Fields" - 2M rows

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX__KeyValue__Field_Value_ID]
ON [dbo].[KeyValue] ([Field],[Value]) INCLUDE ([PersonId])
GO

select PersonId from (
    select PersonId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY PersonId) RowNumber from (
        select PersonId from KeyValue where [Field] = 'Age' and [Value] > 25 union all
        select PersonId from KeyValue where [Field] = 'City' and [Value] = 'Sydney' union all
        select PersonId from KeyValue where [Field] = 'Email' and [Value] = 'xxxxx@gmail.com' union all
        select PersonId from KeyValue where [Field] = 'Name' and [Value] = 'UserName' 
    ) x
) y where RowNumber = 4
--Table 'KeyValue'. Scan count 20, logical reads 1510, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
--Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

select PersonId from (
        select PersonId from KeyValue where [Field] = 'Age' and [Value] > 25 union all
        select PersonId from KeyValue where [Field] = 'City' and [Value] = 'Sydney' union all
        select PersonId from KeyValue where [Field] = 'Email' and [Value] = 'xxxxx@gmail.com' union all
        select PersonId from KeyValue where [Field] = 'Name' and [Value] = 'UserName' 
) x GROUP by PersonId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
--Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
--Table 'KeyValue'. Scan count 4, logical reads 1377, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SELECT key1.PersonId 
FROM KeyValue key1
    INNER JOIN KeyValue key2 ON key1.PersonId = key2.PersonId
    INNER JOIN KeyValue key3 ON key1.PersonId = key3.PersonId
    INNER JOIN KeyValue key4 ON key1.PersonId = key4.PersonId
WHERE key1.[Field] = 'Age' and key1.[Value] > 25
    AND key2.[Field] = 'City' and key2.[Value] = 'Sydney'
    AND key3.[Field] = 'Email' and key3.[Value] = 'xxxxx@gmail.com' 
    AND key4.[Field] = 'Name' and key4.[Value] = 'UserName' 
-- Table 'KeyValue'. Scan count 1, logical reads 21, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following structure:

```
select PersonId from
(
    select PersonId from xxx where [Field] = 'Age' and [Value] > 25
    union all
    select PersonId from xxx where [Field] = 'City' and [Value] = 'New York' 
) x
group by PersonId
having count(*) = 2
```

You can create one more query for the union for each parameter. So this way it will return each `PersonId` as many times as it matches the criteria. Then you can select those `PersonId` that match all the criteria, i.e. `count(*)` equals number of parameters.

You can extend that to more parameters easily.

This should perform well if you have the right indexes on `Field` and `Value`.

---

This is a version without `group by` (though it has the same effect):

```
select PersonId from
(
    select PersonId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY PersonId) RowNumber from
    (
        select PersonId from xxx where [Field] = 'Age' and [Value] > 25
        union all
        select PersonId from xxx where [Field] = 'City' and [Value] = 'Sydney' 
    ) x
) y
where RowNumber = 2
```

Comment: I want to avoid Group by :)

Comment: Which SQL Server version is it for?

Comment: Another version added

Comment: what do you think about the solution AlexK provided?

Comment: It's ok if you have 2 parameters. But what about 5 or 10?

Comment: If you have many parameters check [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504793/sql-design-approach-for-searching-a-table-with-an-unlimited-number-of-bit-fields). Also you can think about [Sparse columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct somthing like this would work:

```
SELECT 
  one.* 
FROM table1 AS one
INNER JOIN table2 AS two1 ON one.Id = two1.PersonId
INNER JOIN table2 AS two2 ON one.Id = two2.PersonId
WHERE (two1.field = 'age' AND two1.value > 25) 
AND (two2.field = 'city' AND two2.value = 'New York')
```

Good luck!

Comment: do you think it would return anything?