# Rewriting comma delimited data to a structured

Tags: mysql, delimiter

I have a table which consists of the headings **Category** and **Subcategories**
 Within the subcategories heading for each category I have a comma separated list of subcategories.

I would like to rewrite the data to a new table so that the comma separated subcategories are in separate rows with the corresponding category in the previous column.

If anyone has any ideas on how to go about this I would be very grateful.

Comment: Check this blog post where a SPLIT_STRING() function is defined:  http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Comment: Another option is to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function and write a procedure that does what you want. There is no `SPLIT()` function in MySQL and this requires a recursive procedure. You either write it as a MySQL procedure or as PHP one (or Python or whatever other language you prefer).

Comment: Here's another question in SO with a procedure that does almost what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077686/is-there-something-analogous-to-a-split-method-in-mysql

Comment: A MySQL stored procedure can be found here:
http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mysql-stored-procedure-split-delimited-string-into-rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to output your data then use a function like PHP's explode to parse it and insert it into your new table.