# Find similar datas from the same table

Tags: mysql, database, html-table

I have a table contains two columns like this. (item name & item description)

```
item_name    item_des

jasmine      beautiful flower & nice smell    
rose         flower
orange       gud fruit
apple        fruit
books        books
```

I want to find matching items from this table on the basis of item name & description ie,
For example the result should be like:

```
item_name    item_des

jasmine      beautiful flower & nice smell    
rose         flower
```

or

```
item_name    item_des

orange       gud fruit
apple        fruit
```

How can I do that in sql?

I don't have any item name or descriptions..I just want to get all the contents of the table which have similar item name or similar description.

Comment: Please describe exactly why jasmine and rose are selected in your first example

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments on other answers I have come to a conclusion that what you want is to get sets of rows from the table and you want each set to have similar values in item_des column. At least that's what your examples present.

The problem is with the way you define 'similar'. As far as I understand you do not want to supply the query with any additional data to define what kind of similarity you are looking for. AshReva and Naryl assumed you do. That's why they propose you use `LIKE '%flower%' or LIKE 'fruit'` in your query.

I guess what you are asking for is how to get the list `('fruit', 'flower', ...)`, because you do not have one. You want a query which will find one for you.

That's not an easy task and it requires a deal of decision making on your side. The task is rather complex so I am not going to supply a ready to run solution. I will present few fairly straightforward steps you need to go thrugh.

First you need to tokenize your item_des field. What you want is another table called t with one field for example called token. After tokenizing your examples you should get a table like such:

```
token
fruit
books
beautiful
flower
&
nice
smell
gud
fruit
flower
```

You will probably have to write your own tokenizing function. Check here: 
[Is there something analogous to a split() method in mySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077686/is-there-something-analogous-to-a-split-method-in-mysql)

Then you remove duplicates (do a `distinct` on the column). So you get:
    token
    fruit
    books
    beautiful
    flower
    &
    nice
    smell
    gud

Then you might want to somehow remove invalid tokens. You might do this manually. You might do an automated match against some set of keywords or a dictionary. You might apply some heuristic, for example remove tokens with length of 1 character.

After that you simply do a match between the two tables, your original table (let's assume it is called input_data) and final table t, which contains your tokens:

```
select item_name, item_des, token
from input_data, t
where item_des like concat('%',t.token,'%')
order by token
```

You should then get something like that:

```
item_name    item_des                         token
jasmine      beautiful flower & nice smell    beautiful
jasmine      beautiful flower & nice smell    &
jasmine      beautiful flower & nice smell    nice
jasmine      beautiful flower & nice smell    smell
rose         flower                           flower
jasmine      beautiful flower & nice smell    flower
orange       gud fruit                        gud
orange       gud fruit                        fruit
apple        fruit                            fruit
books        books                            books
```

I hope this is what you needed.

Answer (score -2):

Please try below code :

```
select * from table_name where item_name like '%flower%' or item_des like '%flower%'
```

Comment: I think this is not she want.she need similar item_name or similar item_des.How she get $Item_name??

Comment: yes.. I don't have any item name or descriptions..I just want to get all the contents of the table which have similar item name or similar description..

Answer (score -3):

It can be done with:

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_des LIKE '%flower%'
```