# MYSQL Split string without length?

Tags: mysql, split

I have a table field that can contain one or more string values. Sometimes it only contains one value, sometimes two, three, four or five values, etc.

These values ​​are separated by commas. How can I do split operation in MYSQL?

Example:

```
1. 1,2,3,4,5,
2. 1,2,3,4,
3. 1,2,3,
4. 1
5. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
```

This Function,requires an integer value containing length information:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
x VARCHAR(255),
delim VARCHAR(12),
pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
delim, "");
```

Comment: It's a very bad idea to store values comma-separated when you are interested in the separate values. If you want to get single rows from the strings, you'd use a recursive query in SQL, available as of MySQL version 8.0.

Comment: See here how to write a tokenzing function in MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077686/is-there-something-analogous-to-a-split-method-in-mysql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: This information is enough for me.